# Gentoo - Cannot get internet to work on installation

Tags: system-installation, network-interface, gentoo

I am trying out Gentoo for the first time on my PC. It is connected via Ethernet cable.

I downloaded the minimal ISO, I booted to the `gentoo` kernel, then I tried running the `ping` command to check for internet connection, but it failed, So I check `ifconfig` and `ip addr` to check if the interface is up, and it was up, showing as `enp2s0`, but it was showing `inet` as `169.x.x.x` instead of `192.168.x.x`.. I also tried `net-setup` and `dhcpcd` to configure the interface, but no luck. I also tried, `modprobe realtek`, `modprobe -r 8169` `modprobe r8169` as my Ethernet is from Realtek, still no luck. What do I need to do to make it work.

Comment: Does your network have a DHCP server? DId you try setting a static IP on the interface?

Comment: After a couple of reboots to the live USB, it worked. No idea what was problem initially. It fixed itself. But now that the system is installed, it is not assigning the correct IP, again its doing `169.x.x.x` instead of `192.168.x.x`.